# Pagination for table in vaadin

Tags: vaadin

Could you please help me in implementing pagination for a table in vaadin? If there is any sample ,it will help me.

Comment: What have you tried ? Can you show us your code ? What is the exact problem you are having ?

Answer (score 8):

You can simply use the PagedTable Add-on: http://vaadin.com/addon/pagedtable

Comment: In paged Addon v r using table.createControls() for pagination. I want show only 5 records per page. But its showing 5 records along with big empty space followed. How to avoid this

Comment: call table.setPageLength(5);