# Can I implement pagination in Vaadin? If yes then how?

Tags: vaadin

I'm trying to implement pagination on table in my project.. I have read some of tutorials and book  but I'm unable to reach there. Can you please guide me about the same?
Thanks

Comment: There is a similar question here that's been answered already [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462605/pagination-for-table-in-vaadin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by composing a "pagination bar" component and then just connect that with a Table or Grid that actually displays the current page. You can find an example from Viritin tests: [MTableWithTraditionalPaging](https://github.com/viritin/viritin/blob/master/src/test/java/org/vaadin/viritin/it/MTableWithTraditionalPaging.java). You can make similar with raw Table or Grid as well, but you'll just then need to wrap your entities in a BeanItemContainer.

Comment: Hello mstahv, Thanks for your answer I have tried same and it is working properly. But, I have used PagedTable for the same and it by default taking  25 as page length. But I want to set page length to 10. I have tried it using PagedTable.setPageLength(10) but it is not working. Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the PagedTable Add-on: http://vaadin.com/addon/pagedtable
They have also given an example and demo for the table pagination.
It was helpful for me.